VSCode shows imported function as not defined, but the script runs correctly
I'm trying to import functions located in a Python file outside of my Visual Studio Code workspace. Let’s say my structure is:
folder/
├── workspace/
│   └── main.py
│       
└── python_scripts/
    └── utils
        └── __init__.py    
        └── functions.py

And let’s say from main.py I want to be able to call the list_files() function present in functions.py (of course I could put this file in my current workspace, but these are utility functions I want to share across many different projects). After (a lot!) of searching and tweaking, I was able to make it work using:
#main.py
sys.path.append('C:\\folder\\python_scripts') 
from utils import * 
list_files()

This script runs without any issues (inside __init__.py there is also some code to add all functions from functions.py to the global name space). However, Visual Studio Code underlines the function list_files() with a warning saying "list_files" is not defined.
Any idea why, and does it mean I messed up (again!) with the import process, even though the script runs?

The environment VS Code uses as a reference to decide what is defined and what isn't does not have list_files(). You fixed that by explicitly adding another location to the Python Path, so that Python finds utils, giving you access to list_files(). But normally you wouldn't be doing this. Instead, either utils would be in the same location as your script (or near it) or utils would be (part of) a package installed into the environment for the script.

@Grismar I understand. What I didn’t say is that before deciding to use this solution, I spent 10 hours trying to get my custom functions work as a development package, but couldn’t make it work. after using pip install -e . from my miniconda environment and within the myfunctions folder, with all correct setup files, conda list could show my package, but when trying to import this package I systematically got "error: module myfunctions not found". And yes I browsed the web for 10 hours for a solution to that, but apparently using a local development package is not trivial in miniconda.

Conda (and thus miniconda) support installing packages with pip, so there's no need to package it specifically for Conda (unless you want to distribute it publicly on Condaforge for example). There are many basic tutorials online that show how to create a basic package in Python. You can either package your package as a wheel, create a Git repo with a normal package structure and install that directly with pip, or (if you don't mind your package being public) put it on PyPI and install it from anywhere.

haha yes I know there are many basic tutorials about that. I tried them all yesterday, during 10 hours. None of them worked. I want specifically to create a local development package, I don’t want to use PyPI nor Git. I didn’t mean I was trying to create a package specifically for Conda, I meant Conda was able to install my development package but not to use it (import was always failing). In the end, I’m so fed up I’m just asking for a quick workaround to make Visual Studio understand these functions are defined, even if it’s not the right way to make this error disappear.

Package as a wheel, this works locally, if you cannot refer to it directly. You chose to put the package in a folder entirely separate from your main script, which suggests you want a package that others can use in a different context as well - either set the Python Path to find the package for the environment you use in development, or if the package isn't part of active development, build it into a wheel and install it. Note that making a lot of noise about the time something took you doesn't change the actual difficulty of the task, and doesn't reflect well on your efforts.

"making a lot of noise about the time something took you doesn't change the actual difficulty of the task": I never said that. But it helps to explain why I was asking for a Visual Studio solution and not a package installation solution. Your "package as a wheel" solution that I just tried again is still throwing lots of errors at me. "doesn't reflect well on your efforts": wrong. spending 10 hours on a package install does reflect well on efforts. Skill is another thing of course.

A relatively simple and effective solution is to add the following codes to your settings.json:
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "C:\\folder\\python_scripts"
]

This will guide Pylance to retrieve the folder.

that’s the kind of solution I’m looking for, unfortunately it does not seem to work as such. I’m still getting my "undefined" error messages after adding my path to this setting variable. Should I import my functions in a different way then or can I keep
sys.path.append(MY_FUNCTIONS_PATH)
from utils import * ?

If folder is your workspace, you could try from python_scripts.utils import *

My folder tree is indicated in my original post. My custom functions are in a completely different folder, not under my workspace.

Regarding your import statement, from utils import * is generally discouraged because it makes it unclear which names are present in the namespace.
It's better to import only the specific functions you need, like from utils import my_function,
or import the module and use the functions with the module prefix, like import utils and then utils.my_function().
